# Detecting (FH)-spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space. A completely metrizable topological vector space $X \subseteq H$ is an (FH)-space if the topology of $X$ is finer than that induced by $H$ (that is the inclusion $X \subseteq H$ is continuous). By the closed graph theorem, any linear subspace of $H$ has **at most one** (FH)-space topology (see Wilansky, "*Modern Methods in Topological Vector Spaces*", Section 5.5). If $Y \subseteq X$ are two (FH)-spaces then the topology of $Y$ is finer than that induced by $X$ and it is strictly finer if and only if $Y$ is not closed in $X$.

As an example, if $K$ is compact Hausdoff and $H := \mathbb{R}^K$ the product space then the usual sup-norm topology on $C(K) \subseteq H$ is quite natural since it is the unique linear topology which is completely metrizable and such that all the evaluations $f \mapsto f(x)$, $x \in K$ are continuous.

**Questions:**

> 1. Are there methods available to detect whether a given linear subspace $X \subseteq H$ can be turned into an (FH)-space? More generally, is there a known characterization of all (FH)-spaces $X \subseteq H$? I am particularly interested in $H = C[0,1]$.

As an example, no linear topology for the polynomials $\varphi \subseteq C[0,1]$ is completely metrizable due to the Baire category theorem ($\varphi$ is the countable union of its closed subspaces consisting of polynomials of degree $\leq n$).

> 2. Let $H$ be a Banach space and $X \subseteq H$ a dense subspace that can not be turned into an (FH)-space. Then the restriction for $X$ to be completely metrizable is too strong. Can in this case $X$ still be equipped with a "nice" and in some sense (unique) canonical linear topology that is possibly "not too far away" from being completely metrizable? This is a rather vaguely formulated question.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the concept, but it seems like the prototypical examples would be the inclusions $C^k[0,1]\subseteq C[0,1]$ for $k$ a natural number or $\infty$, or the inclusions $L^p[0,1]\subseteq L^1[0,1]$. And then you can spice it up with Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Also, don't you need the topology on $X$ to be locally convex?

Comment: @tomasz The usual CGT works for completely metrizable topological vector spaces - local convexity is not required. For Wilansky a "Fréchet space" is such a completely metrizable topological vector space. For the $C^k[0,1]$ spaces take $H := \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. For the $L^p[0,1]$ spaces $p \in [0, \infty]$ take $H := L^0[0,1]$ (equivalence classes of measurable functions) with its usual completely metrizable linear topology. Other examples: For $H = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we have the sequence spaces $l^p$, $p \in [0, \infty]$, $c_0$, etc.

Comment: @tomasz Particular examples of linear subspaces of some topological vector space $H$ that are not (FH)-spaces can be produced by the Baire category theorem: $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} l^n \subseteq c_0$, $C_c(\mathbb{R}) := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \mid \textrm{supp}(f) \subseteq [-n,n] \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} =: H$, etc. So it is rather of interest to answer questions like: Given a particular linear subspace $X \subseteq H$, are there tools (other than the Baire category theorem) to check whether $X$ is an (FH)-space.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237178/attempted-banachification-of-a-space/237214#237214 seems closely related.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for the link to the similar recently asked question on MO (and indirectly for Tao's blog entry). It seems that a solution for this problem (a full characterization of FH-spaces) is not available so far.